# quickblox 500 Internal error REST API call

Tags: quickblox

We want to create Quickblox user through our WEB-Java application.

To get the same working we are trying to first make the REST API calls through Postman and CURL and then proceed to Java Code.

However, we are getting 500 internal error

URL

https://api.quickblox.com/session.json

```
Header
Content-Type: application/json"
QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0
```

body

```
{"application_id": “35221”, "auth_key": "wU8JrJ-DKamUB8v", "timestamp": “1456378718”, "nonce": “1112”, "signature": "81f3967265c87de025010eb9298d169555085e91”}
```

To generate the signature

```
application_id=35221&auth_key=wU8JrJ-DKamUB8v&nonce=1112&timestamp=1456378718
```

Here is the response we are getting `Connection → keep-alive

```
Content-Length → 948
Content-Type → text/html; charset=utf-8
Date → Thu, 25 Feb 2016 05:48:08 GMT
Server → nginx/1.8.0
Status → 500 Internal Server Error
X-Rack-Cache → invalidate, pass
X-Request-Id → 3a47c3daaf9ad353a5b592459c6f3345
X-Runtime → 0.003346`
```

As to my understanding the parameters are as suggested in the API docs. Please help as we are bit stuck at it and are not able to move forward.

Also posting a curl equivalent that results in same error

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0” \
-d '{"application_id": “35221”, "auth_key": "wU8JrJ-DKamUB8v", "timestamp": “1456378718”, "nonce": “1112”, "signature": "81f3967265c87de025010eb9298d169555085e91”}’ \
https://api.quickblox.com/session.json


application_id=35221&auth_key=wU8JrJ-DKamUB8v&nonce=1112&timestamp=1456378718

authorisation secret - FEu2AN8CfgU7VF4
```

thanks,
aakash

Comment: Make sure that you use proper inverted commas everywhere - "" instead of ””

Answer (score 0):

First define all the related to the application:

```
     DEFINE('APPLICATION_ID', 23424);
     DEFINE('AUTH_KEY', "dfsadfasdfsadf-");
     DEFINE('AUTH_SECRET', "23421342134");

     DEFINE('USER_LOGIN', "rahul");
     DEFINE('USER_PASSWORD', "fghdf56456456");       

     // Quickblox endpoints
     DEFINE('QB_API_ENDPOINT', "https://api.quickblox.com");
     DEFINE('QB_PATH_SESSION', "session.json");
```

After define, create signature and pass `$post_body` in curl session api hit, get token and use token in all the `webservices php`:

```
        $nonce = rand();
        $timestamp = time();
        $signature_string = "application_id=".APPLICATION_ID."&auth_key=".AUTH_KEY."&nonce=".$nonce."&timestamp=".$timestamp."&user[login]=".USER_LOGIN."&user[password]=".USER_PASSWORD;
        $signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $signature_string , AUTH_SECRET);
        $post_body = http_build_query(array(
                             'application_id' => APPLICATION_ID,
                             'auth_key' => AUTH_KEY,
                             'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                             'nonce' => $nonce,
                             'signature' => $signature,
                             'user[login]' => USER_LOGIN,
                             'user[password]' => USER_PASSWORD
                             ));
```